# Настройка DNS для доменов 3го уровня

Tags: dns

Решил захостить сайт на своём домашнем серваке. Подключил у провайдера услугу "Статический IP адрес", домен мой делегирован на Яндексе, и на Яндексе в настройках DNS написал:
Хост = @, тип = А, значение записи = 46.x.xxx.196 (мой IP). На роутере, соответственно, пробросил 80ый порт до сервака. Пока обновлялись DNS, я в apache2 создал домен 3го уровня blog.%my_domain%.com и накатил туда свежий WordPress. Прошло что-то около 6 часов, основной домен стал доступен, домен 3го уровня нет. Я позвонил товарищу, он говорит, мол, ты сделай ещё одну A-запись, только в поле "Хост" вместо собачки звёздочку поставь. Я добавил ещё одну запись, получилось так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На данный момент прошло более суток, основной домен 2го уровня доступен отовсюду нормально, а домен 3го уровня с телефона (Yota 4G) загружается отлично, а с моего компа (подключен к тому-же роутеру, что и сервак) грузится оооочень медленно, и в итоге в 90% случаев падает в "Страница не найдена". Я не знаю, где моя ошибка и в чём я накосячил, но мне в общем надо, чтобы ВСЕ запросы *.%my_domain%.com шли на мой IP, а дальше я уже apache'ем регулировал что где обрабатывать и как.

Была мысль, что я что-то ещё упустил помимо DNS, т.к. с компа сайт начинает грузиться, загружается title, загружается фоновая картинка, и потом только всё падает, то есть, может, это и не в DNS дело, но тогда в чём?

P.S. В ходе тестирования путём кидания ссылки знакомым выяснилось, что открывается сайт через раз, у кого-то сначала пишет "Не удаётся получить доступ... бла-бла-бла", и сразу после обновления страницы открывается, у кого-то сразу открывается, у кого-то вообще не открывается. Всё-таки DNS'ы?..

Comment: А если на компе (с которого тормозит) в файле hosts прописать домен и адрес (точнее "адрес домен"), то будет тормозить?

Comment: И не может быть так, что IP "статический", но провайдер все еще использует его через NAT, то есть на нем может висеть несколько юзеров, не только вы?

Comment: @Alexander Zonov если в hosts прописать ip domain, всё равно не грузит ни фига. Это первое. ВТорое - насколько я понял, провайдер даёт именно нормальный IP, для уточнения наверное лучше с техподдержкой пообщаться будет. И третье - пока я последнюю строчу в настройки DNS не добавил, основной домен второго уровня загружался сразу и номально. Вы уверены, что я не накосячил с DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё заработало со звёздочкой. Нужно было просто несколько дней подождать.